# Locking of JVM virtual address space

Tags: java, linux, memory-management, jvm

I've noticied issues with memory being paged to the swap space while performing GC on my Java-application, so I decided to try to solve it using the mlockall system call and this reduced  the STW latencies a lot. However, I'm having troubles understanding what is going on when the system call fails.

The heap is 2048MB and Xms == Xmx, and right after startup mlockall is invoked using JNI. Only the current virtual address space is locked, i.e. the call is...

```
mlockall(MCL_CURRENT)
```

Since this is a Linux system I had to increase the "Max locked memory" limit for the process, otherwise the call would fail.

The question is when I first increased the limit I thought 3GB would be enough for the JVM process, but then the mlockall call fails. At startup the RSS is 2.5GB and virtual is almost 30GB (viewed from top command). When I increase the limit to 15GB then it succeeds.

How come it is unable to lock the RSS of 2.5GB when the limit is 3GB? How come is is able to lock it with 15GB limit when virtual memory is/seems a lot higher than this value? I would really like to have the limit as close to the RSS at startup as possible, otherwise having a limit at all is pretty pointless...

I can't turn off swap entirely on the system, so my last resort is to use mlockall. Also, the system has enough memory so this is not the cause for memory  being paged to the swap space.

Comment: `mlockall()` locks *all* pages mapped to the current process' address space, not only the pages that are already resident - so RSS value is meaningless in this sense.  
  
Perhaps you'd like to lock only certain regions (e.g. Java Heap). In this case scanning through `/proc/self/maps` and locking desired regions with `mlock()` might help.  
  
BTW, have you set `vm.swappiness` to 0?

Comment: Well, well, well - I'm coming from Solaris but swappiness=0 seems to do the trick!